# Find $a$ in the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have the following question :

matrix $A$ isn't diagonalizable while $a \in R$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & a-2 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Find $a$.

I don't really have any idea how to start, how to choose a "way" for this problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: In order for a matrix to not be diagonalizable, you need that the geometric multiplicity is less than the algebraic multiplicity. Meaning.. the number of (linearly independent) eigenvectors is less than the number of roots of the characteristic equation.

Comment: Hint: In order to be non-diagonalizable, there must be at least one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity greater than 1, so the characteristic polynomial must have a double root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a matrix to not be diagonalizable, you need that the geometric multiplicity is less than the algebraic multiplicity. Meaning.. the number of (linearly independent) eigenvectors is less than the number of roots of the characteristic equation. Writing out the characteristic equation:

$$(3-\lambda)((a-\lambda)(-\lambda)-(a-2)(-2)) = (3-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - \lambda a + 2a-4).$$

The roots to this are $3$ (of course) and

$$\frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4(2a-4)}}{2} = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 8a + 16}}{2} = \frac{a \pm (a-4)}{2}$$

which gives $2$ and $a-2$. For which value(s) of $a$ do we get a multiple root (meaning two or more eigenvalues are the same)? Does this/these choice(s) of $a$ give rise to a non-diagonalizable matrix?

Comment: I think when two rows are multiples of each other is means that the geometric multiplicity it increased by 1? since we know it equal to $n-rank(\lambda I-A)$ therefore the $rank$ is increasing, $$$$ Lets see if I get it, I know if I get 3 different eigenvalues there $A$ diagonalizable, therefore I must choose $a$ so the algebraic multiplicity is atleast $2$, in this case $2$ since For $a=3 \implies A$ isn't diagonalizable right?

Comment: My initial comment was mistaken since I was thinking of the matrix $A-\lambda I$. What I said is true about $A-\lambda I$, not $A$. You need $a-2$ to be one of $3$ or $2$ so $a=5$ or $a=4$. In either case, you get an algebraic multiplicity of $2$. However: do both of these give a geometric multiplicity of $1$ (meaning is there only one eigenvector for each)?

Comment: Isn't the characteristic equation wrong? since the formula is meaning that $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
t-3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & t-a & -a+2 \\
0 & 2 & t-0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the second thing is that I don't really get managed to reach to the formula of the root can you please elaborate with your answer?

Comment: There are two competing standards for the characteristic matrices (I guess you'd call them that?): $A-\lambda I$ (which I prefer) and $\lambda I - A$. They carry the exact same information since they are only negatives of each other. To get the formula for the characteristic equation, just take the determinant. Expand along the top row or left column.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand how to get to the characteristic equation but I don't understand how to managed to reach from $$(3-\lambda)((a-\lambda)(-\lambda)-(a-2)(-2)) = (3-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - \lambda a + 2a-4).$$ to $$\frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4(2a-4)}}{2} $$. why did the $\lambda$ gone? have you chose $\lambda=3$?

Comment: Oh I used the quadratic equation to get the roots. I should have put $\lambda = $ in front of that part. My apologies.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, For some reason I still can't get it, maybe it because it really late here, instand of asking lots of questions I'll go to sleep and I'll try to understand it tomorrow.

Comment: You're very welcome. Sometimes a good night's rest is all you need. If you need any further help on this problem tomorrow, just ping me again and I'll help you out.

Comment: Ok lets see if I understand it now, so in order for a matrix to not be diagonalizable we need to have the geometric multiplicity less than the algebraic multiplicity, we know that in case the algebraic multiplicity is one $\implies$ geometric multiplicity is also one, So we must look for a for an eigenvalue with at least double root.

Comment: We calculated the characteristic equation of $A$ and we look for what make is zero meaning that $$det|A-\lambda I |=0$$ in order to find the eigenvalues of $A$, and choose $a$ accordingly, so the algebraic multiplicity will at least be with double root.

Comment: After using the quadratic equation we know that $$\lambda = 2,2-a,3$$ Therefore we received three eigenvalues, and we want $2-a$ to create a double root so we can get that $A$ is not diagonalizable incase $a=0$ we receive the eigenvalue $2$ is with algebraic multiplicity of $2$,  $$$$ and also for $a=-1$ we receive that the eigenvalue $3$ is with algebraic multiplicity of $2$, and now we need to check for each of $a=0,-1$ the geometric multiplicity of $A$ for that eigenvalue and find where $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: I apologize for multiple comments is just that all of the written above wouldn't enter in a single one.

Comment: You're almost right. It's $2-a$ not $a-2$ for the other eigenvalue.

Comment: Oh, your right therefore $$a=5,4$$ and we know that $\lambda$ has double root therefore we need to check the geometric multiplicity for $$a= 5, \lambda=3$$ and for $$a=4, \lambda=2$$ and see which one of them has a geometric multiplicity low than the algebraic multiplicity, and then we can conclude the value for $a$, right?

Comment: Yep that is exactly right.